# is it possible to use url as selector

Tags: jquery

I have a site called site.com and I want to check if the classname is present on my other page http://site.com/subfolder and if it is yes then perform the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($('http://site.com/subfolder classname').length > 0) {
        $('.headline').after('<div>text</div>');
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you cannot.. That would be almost magical.

Comment: Try this, slements = $('a[href=http://site.com].classname');

Comment: possible duplicate of [What characters are valid in CSS class names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names)

Comment: why do u want to do that ???

Comment: You should tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: @vega: it's not, see my answer, straight from the docs.

Comment: @11684 You're not using a URL as a selector. To be able to do so would be as Vega said, "almost magical".

Comment: No, not as a selector, but the result is almost the same, isn't it? @JayBlanchard

Comment: No, the result isn't almost the same. The OP is unclear about his purposes but he does not carry the URL into the function, he only uses it as a conditional check. He should, as @Patrick James McDougle points out, try to tell us what he is trying to do.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for responding. Apologize if my post is incomplete. I added more details above hopefully it will help you more understand what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks ahead.

Comment: I think you are going to have to do this server side. There isn't going to be any easy way to pull the html from a site with a different domain.

Comment: HI sir thanks for responding. I am not sure about the different domain. The code where the classname can be found is on the same domain. Example I have a domain called amkitty.com and the url of the classname that I want to check is from amkitty.com/subfolder. Does that still needs server side client?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector with a URL in it such as :

```
$('a[href="url"].classname')
```

but not in the way you are using it

Answer (score 0):

You can select an element from another page with the `.load()` method.

Example:

```
$("#myElement").load("http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588441/is-it-possible-to-use-url-as-selector #question");
```

This will load the div with the id `question` from this page in the element with the id `myElement` (if there were no cross domain policy).

For more information see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments).